# UTF-8 problems with characters from MySQL database (e.g. é as Ã©)

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8

I know there are hundreds of questions about UTF-8 woes but I tried all the approaches I could find, none of them helped.

The facts:
I'm trying to read a string that contains a **é** from my MySQL database and display it on a PHP page. Actually, it does display as é (but the font does not recognize it as such and thus another default font is used). The troubles arose when I wanted to convert this string to a filename using PHP functions for string replacement. PHP does not recognize this as the é character at all.

Here's a quick rundown of what I'm doing:

1) The String is stored in a MySQL database. The MySQL server settings are:
MySQL connection collation utf8_unicode_ci
MySQL charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)
The database itself is set to collation utf8_unicode_ci (MyISAM storage engine, not changeable due to shared server)
The actual table is set to collcation utf8_unicode_ci (InnoDB storage engine)

The é shows up correctly in phpMyAdmin. The data is inserted into the DB via a Java program but I have also tried this with manually entered data (entered in phpMyAdmin).

2) The PHP default_charset is not set (NO VALUE), I'm on a shared server and placing a manual override php.ini did not seem to work. Using `ini_set("default_charset", 'utf-8');` works but has no effect on the problem I have.

3) Before I run the actual select query I query `SET NAMES 'utf8'`. The query itself is irrelevant but for testing I chose a simple `SELECT title FROM items WHERE item_id = 1`

4) The PHP file itself is encoded UTF-8. I have set the correct charset for the html with `<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />`

5) To test the problem I used htmlentities on the returned string (Astérix), checking the source code it is converted to `Ast&Atilde;&copy;rix` which is not correct of course. Accordingly, the string shows up as `AstÃ©rix` in the browser.

What possible reason could there be for this? To me it seems like I set everything that can be set to UTF-8.

Comment: I explicitly said I did research this right here on SO but none of the offered solutions (most of which I actually mention in the text) helped. As you impossibly read the actual question less than 1 minute after I posted it I can only assume you went "another idiotic UTF question, DUPE" without thinking. Thanks, very much appreciated :/

Comment: Then you didn't search enough. really.

Comment: Yes, of course, that must be it. Just check some of the "related" questions showing up on the right. None of them even mention the multibyte functions. They all assume (often rightfully) that the storage or retrieval at some place breaks the UTF-8 chain, which isn't the case here as Joe pointed out. And I'm fairly certain you didn't think "Oh, obvious, just use the multibyte functions" when posting your useless comment, otherwise you'd just have mentioned that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://php.net/manual/en/ref.mbstring.php - look at multibyte string functions.

Comment: So you're saying I'm doing nothing wrong storing and retrieving the data from the database but I'm "just" using the wrong PHP functions to handle it?

Comment: Looks like it - like you say, everything is set to use UTF-8 except when you echo it it's not being treated as UTF-8. PHP doesn't automatically detect the charset of the string (it loves ISO-8859-1 :P), so you have to give it a hand, hence the multibyte functions.

Comment: I just checked this using the explicit `htmlentities($string,ENT_COMPAT, "UTF-8")` version of htmlentities and it does confirm your suspicion. Thanks a lot :)