# Charset changing when reloading or refreshing the page

Tags: html, character-encoding

I have an ASP.NET page with the encoding defined in the header that loads with the proper encoding only once, then shows the data with no encoding (ASCII?).

The HTML header is written like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" >
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html" /> 
<meta http-equiv="charset" content="utf-8" />
```

The data that should appear as UTF-8 is fetched from a nvarchar cell in SQL and put in a cookie in ASP.Net. When the page reloads the first time, it appears ok:

```
Salé
```

Then for all other redirects / refreshes, it appears as:

```
SalÃ©
```

The charset meta is in the source when checking the bad page's source in a browser.

Is my header wrong? If not, I'll dig deeper into my code.

[EDIT]

I tried to change the header programmatically with a runat="server" in the `<head>`, but it wasn't working.

```
Dim meta As System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlMeta = New System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlMeta()
meta.HttpEquiv = "content-type"
meta.Content = Response.ContentType + "; charset=" + Response.ContentEncoding.HeaderName
Page.Header.Controls.Add(meta)
```

[EDIT]

Found a similar issue: [UTF-8 problems with characters from MySQL database (e.g. é as Ã©)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9179763/utf-8-problems-with-characters-from-mysql-database-e-g-e-as-a)

Comment: try this and remove both `<meta>` from your file `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />`

Comment: Not working, that's what I had before I split it into two parts to see if it works better.

Comment: Try this `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type"
content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />`

Comment: Not working either. I think that these Meta are more or less the same. Really a weird problem. I'll look into the server settings.

Comment: Really weird, do let me know if you find out the solution